# Is it possible to remove a break point set with ipdb.set_trace()?

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

I used `ipdb.set_trace()` somewhere in my Python code. Is it possible to ignore this break point using a IPDB command?

`clear` tells me that it cleared all break points, but IPDB stops again when it stumbles upon the line with `ipdb.set_trace()`.

`disable 1` tells me: `No breakpoint numbered 1`
`ignore 1` says: `Breakpoint index '1' is not valid`

To clarify: Of course I could simply remove the break point from my source code. But this would require to quit the debugger and to start it again. Often it needs a lot of work to get somewhere and restarting the debugger makes life more difficult. Also if there is a huge loop and you want inspect objects in the loop, the easiest is to place a break point in the loop directly after the object. How could I then skip the loop (and all thousands of calls `set_trace()`) and step through the code after the loop using `next`?

Comment: breakpoints are only for debugging, It is a good idea to keep track of _where_ you have set it. You are better off doing a `grep` or a search to figure out where it is.

Comment: @karthikr Yes, of course. I think you misunderstood my question a bit. I tried to clarify how I'd like to use the debugger.

Answer (score 49):

Well, you CAN take advantage of the fact that anything in Python is an object. While in the debugger, you can do something like this:

```
def f(): pass
ipdb.set_trace = f
```

set_trace will still be called, but it won't do anything.
Of course, it's somewhat permanent, but you can just do

```
reload ipdb
```

and you'll get the original behaviour back.

(why would you do this? when you accidentally put a breakpoint in an often-called function that is usually called under a try/except. Once you realize you're stopping 1000 times in this function, you try to ctrl-c, but that gets caught by the try/except and you're back in ipdb again. So, if you're in low-level code, make sure your set_traces have some context:

```
if myvar in ['some', 'sentinel', 'values']:
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

etc.

Comment: +1 for the great suggestion of simply overwriting `set_trace()`. Anyhow, this does not enable to delete a specific break point.

Comment: it should be possible to extend this concept to eliminate just a single breakpoint, by using the inspect module to determine the current file/line, and either return (doing nothing) or call the original ipdb.set_trace(). i don't have a recipe but i have had use of this a couple times so this is inspiring me to put one together...

Comment: This happens to me quite a bit when working with test suites. If you're stuck and just want your shell prompt back, a simple `del ipdb.set_trace` works like a charm.

Answer (score 28):

After learning from Corley

```
ipdb.set_trace = lambda: None
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Corley and GLaDOS answers, you can use this trick to set_trace for **several loops** without overwriting the **ipdb.set_trace()**

```
import ipdb
dbg1 = ipdb.set_trace  # BREAKPOINT
for i in range(10):
    my_var2 = 10 / 3
    dbg1()  # BREAKPOINT
    dbg1 = lambda: None
    print(my_var2)


dbg2 = ipdb.set_trace  # BREAKPOINT
for i in range(10):
    my_var2 = 20 / 3
    dbg2()  # BREAKPOINT
    dbg2 = lambda: None
    print(my_var2)
```

Works for me like a charm.

Comment: This is the best one so far on here, you can set multiple break points and they do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score -4):

Running the program should also tell you exactly where you've set your `idb.set_trace()` when it's being hit (otherwise, try the `where` or `bt` commands). You can then remove that line from the file, and restart the program.

Otherwise, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573599/change-python-source-while-running) useful, if you feel more experimental.